# Can a sql query perform this job?

Tags: mysql

Here is my schema:

```
    CREATE TABLE `tbltransactions` (
    `transactionid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `transactiondate` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `customerid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `transactiondetail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `transactionamount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY `transactionid` (`transactionid`),
    KEY `customerid` (`customerid`),
    CONSTRAINT `tbltransactions_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customerid`) REFERENCES `tblcustomers`   (`customerid`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=240 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

transactionamount contains positive values for purchases and negative values for payments.

I wish I could list all records onwards from tbltransactions where customer's balance was zero at the latest. Any help?

EDIT: Please consider this dataset:

```
    purchase    10
    payment     -10 // balance is zero
    purchase    5
    payment     -5 // balance again zero
    purchase    7 // show this transaction and onwards
    purchase    2
    payment         -5 // show this also since balance is not zero
```

EDIT: sample of actual data:

```
INSERT INTO `tbltransactions` VALUES (1,'2014-06-22 22:51:00',39,'Balance when computerized',8851.00),(2,'2014-06-22 22:55:05',35,'Balance when computerized',5395.00),(3,'2014-06-22 22:56:17',53,'Balance when computerized',60.00),(4,'2014-06-22 22:57:15',54,'Balance when computerized',2671.00),(5,'2014-06-22 22:57:41',55,'Balance when computerized',1586.00),(6,'2014-06-22 22:58:34',61,'Balance when computerized',50.00),(7,'2014-06-22 22:59:22',56,'Balance when computerized',344.00),(8,'2014-06-22 22:59:42',71,'Balance when computerized',650.00),(9,'2014-06-22 23:01:10',63,'Balance when computerized',1573.00),(10,'2014-06-22 23:01:51',32,'Balance when computerized',7515.00),(11,'2014-06-22 23:02:22',72,'Balance when computerized',466.00),(12,'2014-06-22 23:03:10',64,'Balance when computerized',4774.00),(13,'2014-06-22 23:03:32',42,'Balance when computerized',2992.00),(14,'2014-06-22 23:05:24',41,'Balance when computerized',2218.00),(15,'2014-06-22 23:05:39',40,'Balance when computerized',7149.00),(16,'2014-06-22 23:06:25',80,'Balance when computerized',2607.00),(17,'2014-06-22 23:09:18',67,'Balance when computerized',357.00),(18,'2014-06-22 23:20:39',10,'Balance when computerized',677.00),(19,'2014-06-22 23:13:17',57,'Balance when computerized',135.00),(20,'2014-06-22 23:13:47',58,'Balance when computerized',5872.00),(21,'2014-06-24 11:36:10',73,'Balance when computerized',355.00),(22,'2014-06-22 23:14:30',74,'Balance when computerized',173.00),(23,'2014-06-22 23:16:45',59,'Balance when computerized',995.00),(24,'2014-06-22 23:17:44',19,'Balance when computerized',1704.00),(25,'2014-06-22 23:19:00',23,'Balance when computerized',690.00),(26,'2014-06-22 23:21:17',34,'Balance when computerized',10331.00),(27,'2014-06-22 23:21:43',38,'Balance when computerized',495.00),(28,'2014-06-22 23:22:01',65,'Balance when computerized',6676.00),(29,'2014-06-22 23:23:31',8,'Balance when computerized',4148.00),(30,'2014-06-22 23:23:53',24,'Balance when computerized',3124.00),(31,'2014-06-22 23:27:02',68,'Balance when computerized',3364.00),(35,'2014-06-22 23:35:22',46,'Balance when computerized',19105.00),(36,'2014-06-22 23:36:26',36,'Balance when computerized',2471.00),(37,'2014-06-22 23:36:42',60,'Balance when computerized',910.00),(38,'2014-06-22 23:37:11',75,'Balance when computerized',5203.00),(39,'2014-06-22 23:37:29',77,'Balance when computerized',2342.00),(40,'2014-06-22 23:37:42',13,'Balance when computerized',4555.00),(41,'2014-06-22 23:38:24',62,'Balance when computerized',271.00),(42,'2014-06-22 23:42:43',26,'Balance when computerized',5040.00),(43,'2014-06-22 23:43:13',33,'Balance when computerized',6792.00),(44,'2014-06-22 23:43:57',9,'Balance when computerized',1101.00),(45,'2014-06-22 23:44:27',21,'Balance when computerized',1010.00),(46,'2014-06-22 23:45:16',69,'Balance when computerized',89.00),(47,'2014-06-22 23:45:52',81,'Balance when computerized',220.00),(48,'2014-06-22 23:46:37',82,'Balance when computerized',205.00),(49,'2014-06-22 23:47:26',83,'Balance when computerized',731.00),(50,'2014-06-22 23:48:00',84,'Balance when computerized',155.00),(51,'2014-06-22 23:48:54',5,'Balance when computerized',475.00),(52,'2014-06-22 23:50:13',85,'Balance when computerized',1375.00),(53,'2014-06-22 23:51:04',86,'Balance when computerized',28.00),(54,'2014-06-22 23:51:39',87,'Balance when computerized',26.00),(55,'2014-06-22 23:52:23',88,'Balance when computerized',30.00),(56,'2014-06-22 23:52:53',89,'Balance when computerized',45.00),(57,'2014-06-22 23:53:23',90,'Balance when computerized',140.00),(58,'2014-06-22 23:54:13',91,'Balance when computerized',40.00),(59,'2014-06-22 23:55:38',93,'Balance when computerized',3350.00),(60,'2014-06-22 23:57:13',3,'Balance when computerized',60.00),(61,'2014-06-22 23:59:05',94,'Balance when computerized',3372.00),(62,'2014-06-23 00:00:12',20,'Balance when computerized',562.00),(63,'2014-06-23 00:00:48',18,'Balance when computerized',3227.00),(64,'2014-06-23 00:01:26',7,'Balance when computerized',1023.00),(65,'2014-06-23 00:01:46',29,'Balance when computerized',20.00),(66,'2014-06-23 00:02:57',15,'Balance when computerized',160.00),(67,'2014-06-23 00:04:14',11,'Balance when computerized',345.00),(68,'2014-06-23 00:04:50',31,'Balance when computerized',45.00),(69,'2014-06-23 00:08:45',50,'Balance when computerized',50.00),(70,'2014-06-23 00:09:05',6,'Balance when computerized',2880.00),(71,'2014-06-23 00:11:29',96,'Balance when computerized',1300.00),(72,'2014-06-23 00:12:40',4,'Balance when computerized',601.00),(74,'2014-06-24 10:21:26',97,'Balance when computerized',1250.00),(76,'2014-06-24 10:35:31',32,'1.5 ltr etc.',510.00),(77,'2014-06-24 15:04:13',97,'parchi',535.00),(78,'2014-06-24 15:05:51',32,'parchi',400.00),(79,'2014-06-24 15:08:08',32,'parchi',1924.00),(80,'2014-06-24 15:14:38',35,'suger berd',840.00),(81,'2014-06-24 15:16:49',39,'bottel',85.00),(82,'2014-06-24 15:21:51',20,'salt tusho',250.00),(83,'2014-06-24 15:23:49',26,'eggs',45.00),(84,'2014-06-24 15:24:54',38,'waldah',200.00),(85,'2014-06-24 15:26:12',78,'Balance when computerized',1557.00),(86,'2014-06-24 15:27:12',78,'haldi',70.00),(87,'2014-06-24 15:28:37',68,'eggs butter',87.00),(88,'2014-06-24 15:30:19',98,'Balance when computerized',550.00),(89,'2014-06-24 15:32:13',44,'2 coke',50.00),(90,'2014-06-24 15:33:05',81,'self',-220.00),(91,'2014-06-24 15:33:52',46,'razor',30.00),(92,'2014-06-24 15:34:37',75,'dues',40.00),(93,'2014-06-24 15:35:35',9,'oil ghee',625.00),(94,'2014-06-24 15:36:57',99,'bread',93.00),(95,'2014-06-24 15:38:14',100,'bottle razor',55.00),(96,'2014-06-24 15:38:54',7,'dues',40.00),(97,'2014-06-24 15:39:41',75,'ltr',60.00),(98,'2014-06-24 15:40:08',69,'1.5 ltr',60.00),(99,'2014-06-24 15:40:27',42,'2 1.5 ltr',120.00),(100,'2014-06-24 15:42:02',26,'bread bottle',110.00),(101,'2014-06-24 15:45:39',78,'saman',140.00),(102,'2014-06-26 15:19:20',101,'Oil dues',105.00),(103,'2014-06-26 15:19:59',26,'bread etc',55.00),(104,'2014-06-26 15:20:15',97,'parchi',290.00),(105,'2014-06-26 15:20:33',35,'parchi',355.00),(106,'2014-06-26 15:20:46',81,'bread',100.00),(107,'2014-06-26 15:21:26',102,'razor',40.00),(108,'2014-06-26 15:22:51',38,'dues',30.00),(109,'2014-06-26 15:23:35',20,'register, bottle',275.00),(110,'2014-06-26 15:23:55',46,'bottle dues etc',540.00),(112,'2014-06-26 15:26:08',46,'wife',-5000.00),(113,'2014-06-26 15:26:52',39,'bottle',65.00),(114,'2014-06-26 15:27:05',66,'1.5 ltr',85.00),(115,'2014-06-26 15:27:22',34,'cheeni etc',780.00),(116,'2014-06-26 15:27:46',97,'parchi',260.00),(117,'2014-06-26 15:28:04',81,'surf',370.00),(118,'2014-06-26 15:28:38',103,'rooh afza',150.00),(119,'2014-06-26 15:28:57',35,'parchi oil etc',623.00),(120,'2014-06-26 15:29:19',52,'easy paisa',1060.00),(121,'2014-06-26 15:29:51',35,'cake 1.5 ltr',185.00),(122,'2014-06-26 15:30:06',97,'parchi',243.00),(123,'2014-06-26 15:32:04',18,'dues',13.00),(124,'2014-06-26 15:32:28',26,'bread',50.00),(125,'2014-06-26 15:33:47',78,'bread',150.00),(126,'2014-06-26 15:34:52',9,'cheeni',280.00),(127,'2014-06-26 15:36:17',20,'oil',205.00),(128,'2014-06-26 15:39:31',96,'more load',500.00),(129,'2014-06-26 15:40:38',75,'water etc',125.00),(130,'2014-06-26 15:40:57',35,'dues',30.00),(131,'2014-06-26 15:41:10',18,'half role',90.00),(132,'2014-06-26 15:41:32',88,'geometery dues',20.00),(133,'2014-06-26 15:41:56',4,'dues',10.00),(134,'2014-06-26 15:42:18',41,'dues',60.00),(135,'2014-06-26 15:42:36',20,'ciggeret half role',190.00),(136,'2014-06-26 15:43:02',87,'always',30.00),(137,'2014-06-26 15:43:42',104,'dues',73.00),(138,'2014-06-26 15:44:07',13,'dues',946.00),(139,'2014-06-26 15:44:20',18,'surf',130.00),(140,'2014-06-26 15:44:29',35,'parchi',240.00),(141,'2014-06-26 15:44:46',85,'dues',30.00),(142,'2014-06-26 15:45:05',75,'milk',140.00),(143,'2014-06-26 15:45:24',74,'cream',40.00),(144,'2014-06-26 15:45:39',88,'milk',40.00),(145,'2014-06-26 15:46:00',38,'perfume',90.00),(146,'2014-06-26 15:46:20',32,'chilka etc',70.00),(147,'2014-06-26 15:47:05',90,'payment',-140.00),(148,'2014-06-26 15:47:26',18,'ghee dues',30.00),(149,'2014-06-26 15:47:45',98,'color',15.00),(150,'2014-06-26 15:48:00',85,'taala',50.00),(151,'2014-06-26 15:48:25',103,'ball',15.00),(153,'2014-06-26 15:51:21',64,'catchup',130.00),(154,'2014-06-26 15:51:42',65,'dues',10.00),(155,'2014-06-26 15:52:10',20,'dues',10.00),(156,'2014-06-26 15:52:35',18,'mirch',115.00),(157,'2014-06-26 15:52:56',18,'dues',10.00),(158,'2014-06-26 15:53:13',46,'half role etc',150.00),(159,'2014-06-26 15:53:37',33,'ghee',330.00),(160,'2014-06-26 15:54:06',36,'dues',10.00),(161,'2014-06-26 15:54:37',18,'dues',10.00),(162,'2014-06-26 15:54:50',18,'dues',30.00),(163,'2014-06-26 15:55:20',99,'dues',10.00),(164,'2014-06-26 15:58:14',92,'maidah',30.00),(165,'2014-06-26 16:16:23',26,'dues',856.00),(166,'2014-06-26 16:18:28',20,'load plus others',562.00),(167,'2014-06-26 16:51:35',75,'chanay',50.00),(168,'2014-06-26 16:54:22',103,'dettol',17.00),(169,'2014-06-26 16:55:00',42,'load',100.00),(171,'2014-06-26 17:15:23',85,'dues',125.00),(172,'2014-06-26 17:17:40',46,'tape',25.00),(173,'2014-06-26 17:33:50',66,'chana',40.00),(174,'2014-06-26 17:35:11',75,'shampoo',5.00),(175,'2014-06-26 17:36:37',106,'wiper',50.00),(176,'2014-06-26 17:37:23',43,'bottle',15.00),(177,'2014-06-26 17:37:51',87,'dues',60.00),(178,'2014-06-26 17:38:05',100,'bottle brush',125.00),(179,'2014-06-26 17:38:29',36,'shampoo',180.00),(180,'2014-06-26 17:39:49',32,'dues',20.00),(181,'2014-06-26 17:40:01',55,'dues',7.00),(182,'2014-06-26 17:41:01',41,'dues',15.00),(183,'2014-06-26 18:55:39',66,'bar haf',50.00),(184,'2014-06-26 19:40:30',103,'payment',-150.00),(185,'2014-06-26 20:24:00',61,'chohay maar',30.00),(186,'2014-06-26 21:47:45',97,'payment',-2578.00),(187,'2014-06-26 23:51:17',35,'boteletc',70.00),(188,'2014-06-27 00:00:18',66,'half',17.00),(189,'2014-06-27 00:02:05',99,'self',-107.00),(190,'2014-06-27 00:03:00',68,'tazab',30.00),(192,'2014-06-27 00:07:15',75,'due',25.00),(193,'2014-06-27 00:12:15',108,'dal',35.00),(194,'2014-06-27 00:14:54',57,'due',20.00),(195,'2014-06-27 00:15:30',65,'sig',45.00),(196,'2014-06-27 00:16:21',69,'shapener',15.00),(197,'2014-06-27 00:17:36',39,'botel',150.00),(198,'2014-06-27 00:19:27',37,'ice juice',140.00),(199,'2014-06-27 00:20:31',8,'sweet',250.00),(200,'2014-06-27 00:22:27',106,'botel',20.00),(201,'2014-06-27 00:23:24',22,'due',15.00),(202,'2014-06-27 00:24:08',81,'due',15.00),(203,'2014-06-27 00:26:31',19,'juice',50.00),(204,'2014-06-27 00:29:03',91,'kochyetc',30.00),(205,'2014-06-27 10:16:40',20,'payment',-2054.00),(206,'2014-06-27 10:39:38',78,'bread eggs',135.00),(208,'2014-06-27 10:41:27',74,'payment',-120.00),(209,'2014-06-27 10:45:24',109,'Balance when computerized',12287.00),(210,'2014-06-27 11:04:40',57,'payment',-155.00),(211,'2014-06-27 11:04:55',68,'blue band',55.00),(212,'2014-06-27 11:14:37',32,'sarmad soday',959.00),(213,'2014-06-27 11:28:59',78,'biscuit',40.00),(214,'2014-06-27 11:54:03',71,'bun',30.00),(215,'2014-06-27 15:26:06',92,'cocomo',20.00),(216,'2014-06-27 15:26:20',100,'paste',110.00),(217,'2014-06-27 15:26:48',71,'20 out of 30',-20.00),(218,'2014-06-27 15:27:22',32,'chetos',30.00),(219,'2014-06-27 15:27:44',75,'ghee cheeni',233.00),(220,'2014-06-27 15:29:32',18,'dues',45.00),(221,'2014-06-27 15:30:25',3,'ball',50.00),(222,'2014-06-27 15:31:15',100,'2 bottles',50.00),(223,'2014-06-27 15:32:10',3,'payment',-110.00),(224,'2014-06-27 15:32:38',4,'chips',40.00),(225,'2014-06-27 15:34:11',75,'ghee cheeni daal chawal',433.00),(226,'2014-06-27 15:34:52',41,'spray',400.00),(227,'2014-06-27 21:24:38',40,'katch bred',351.00),(228,'2014-06-27 22:02:04',8,'botel',60.00),(229,'2014-06-27 23:58:40',78,'half',90.00),(230,'2014-06-27 23:59:56',68,'rice',190.00),(231,'2014-06-28 00:00:40',97,'parchi',400.00),(232,'2014-06-28 00:01:15',97,'milk',70.00),(233,'2014-06-28 00:01:53',16,'ice',250.00),(234,'2014-06-28 00:02:53',35,'sig cake',20.00),(235,'2014-06-28 00:03:41',46,'botel cake',95.00),(236,'2014-06-28 00:05:17',75,'parchi rice bottels',750.00),(237,'2014-06-28 00:06:47',78,'sigret wife etc',230.00),(238,'2014-06-28 00:07:23',37,'nimko',10.00),(239,'2014-06-28 00:07:59',41,'rice',160.00);
```

Comment: There's no balance infomration in the table. Do you want to calculate a running total for each customer? What do you mean by "balance was zero at the latest?" Which transactions do you want to list? Please show some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: it's running total calculated from transactionamount coloumn.

Comment: Please consider this dataset: purchase 10
payment  -10 // balance is zero
purchase 5
payment  -5 // balance again zero
purchase 7 // show this transaction and onwards
purchase 2

Comment: Please put it in the question, you can't put formatted information in comments.

Comment: Maybe this is performance heavy, but you could create a view with three columns: `customer`, `date` and `balance`. If you have that, simply select the first (not first in DB but with earliest time stamp) row with `balance <= 0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tbltransactions AS a
JOIN (
    SELECT customerid, MAX(transactiondate) last_zero_bal FROM (
        SELECT customerid, transactiondate, 
               @balance := IF (customerid = @prev_cust, 
                               @balance + transactionamount, 
                               transactionamount) AS balance,
               @prev_cust := customerid
        FROM (SELECT *
              FROM tbltransactions
              ORDER BY customerid, transactiondate) AS t
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @balance := 0, @prev_cust := NULL) AS v
        ) AS running_balances
    WHERE balance = 0
    GROUP BY customerid
    ) AS b ON a.customerid = b.customerid AND a.transactiondate > b.last_zero_bal
```

The subquery with the alias `running_balances` calculates each customer's running balance. Then the subquery `b` finds the most recent date where each customer had a zero balance. Finally, this is joined with the original transaction table to show all the transactions after this.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bde9/2)

Comment: [insert some deity], that was quick.

Comment: @Barmar ... Sorry the query does not return any row

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: @Barmar sorry don't know how to make sqlfiddle ... I have added sample of actual data in edit

Comment: You go to sqlfiddle.com, and put the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements into the DDL box.

Comment: Sorry, I started writing it for a single customer, then changed to grouping by customer, but didn't fix everything. Try it now. Unfortunately, sqlfiddle seems to be having trouble so I haven't been able to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
select b.*
from (
    select a.customerid, max(a.transactionid) last_zero_transactionid
    from (
        select a.customerid, a.transactionid, 
          if(@prev_customer_id=customerid, @running_total:=@running_total+@last_transaction, @running_total:=0) running_total,
          @prev_customer_id:=customerid prev_customer_id,
          @last_transaction:=transactionamount last_transaction
        from tbltransactions a
        join (select @prev_customer_id:=0, @running_total:=0, @last_transaction:=0) b
        order by customerid, transactionid) a
    where a.running_total = 0
    group by a.customerid) a
join tbltransactions b on a.customerid = b.customerid and a.last_zero_transactionid <= b.transactionid;
```

Comment: Does not return anything on actual data. I have added sample data in second edit. Please check it

Comment: @user3762808, see the updated answer. tested against your sample data

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.* FROM
tbltransactions t1
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(t1.transactionid) max_zero_id, t1.customerid
    FROM tbltransactions t1
    JOIN tbltransactions t2 ON t1.customerid = t2.customerid
        AND t1.transactiondate >= t2.transactiondate
    GROUP BY t1.transactiondate, t1.customerid
    HAVING SUM(t2.transactionamount) = 0
) t2 ON t1.transactionid > t2.max_zero_id AND t2.customerid = t1.customerid
ORDER BY t1.customerid, t1.transactionid
```

**Output**

```
+---------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| transactionid | transactiondate     | customerid | transactiondetail | transactionamount |
+---------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|           106 | 2014-06-26 15:20:46 |         81 | bread             |            100.00 |
|           117 | 2014-06-26 15:28:04 |         81 | surf              |            370.00 |
|           202 | 2014-06-27 00:24:08 |         81 | due               |             15.00 |
|           231 | 2014-06-28 00:00:40 |         97 | parchi            |            400.00 |
|           232 | 2014-06-28 00:01:15 |         97 | milk              |             70.00 |
+---------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

**Query Plan**

```
+----+-------------+------------+------+--------------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys            | key        | key_len | ref                | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------+------+--------------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL  | NULL                     | NULL       | NULL    | NULL               |    6 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t1         | ref  | transactionid,customerid | customerid | 8       | t2.customerid      |    1 | Using where                     |
|  2 | DERIVED     | t1         | ALL  | customerid               | NULL       | NULL    | NULL               |  229 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | t2         | ref  | customerid               | customerid | 8       | test.t1.customerid |    1 | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+------------+------+--------------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Using a self-join to calculate running totals is a very expensive way to do this, as it creates an O(n^2) derived table.

Comment: @Barmar the query plan for this query seems to be more efficient than yours

Comment: OK. They seem to take about the same amount of time, I've put them both in a sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf97c/3